# Assign value if UserID and raceID and prediction in predictions table and outcome table match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a F1 poule into which users enter a prediction. They predict who will drive 1st, 2nd, 3rd, pole position and fastest lap. I have that in a table with all foreign keys called race.

[Table race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1joI3.jpg)

| id_voorspel | id_user | id_race | Pole_position | 1e | 2e | 3e | sr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 |

It is linked to a table with primary key with all the driver information.

[Table driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsI1r.jpg)

| id | racenummer | naam | naam_1e | naam_2e | naam_3e | naam_pp | naam _ sr | land_id | team_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Max Verstappen | Max Verstappen | Max Verstappen | Max Verstappen | Max Verstappen | Max Verstappen | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | Sergio Perez | Sergio Perez | Sergio Perez | Sergio Perez | Sergio Perez | Sergio Perez | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 44 | Lewis Hamilton | Lewis Hamilton | Lewis Hamilton | Lewis Hamilton | Lewis Hamilton | Lewis Hamilton | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 63 | George Russell | George Russell | George Russell | George Russell | George Russell | George Russell | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 24 | Zhou Guanyu | Zhou Guanyu | Zhou Guanyu | Zhou Guanyu | Zhou Guanyu | Zhou Guanyu | 13 | 3 |
| 6 | 77 | Valtteri Bottas | VaItteri Bottas | Valtteri Bottas | Valtteri Bottas | Valtteri Bottas | Valtteri Bottas | 14 | 3 |
| 7 | 21 | Nyck de Vries | Nyck de Vries | Nyck de Vries | Nyck de Vries | Nyck de Vries | Nyck de Vries | 1 | 4 |
| 8 | 22 | Yuki Tsunoda | Yuki Tsunoda | Yuki Tsunoda | Yuki Tsunoda | Yuki Tsunoda | Yuki Tsunoda | 15 | 4 |
| 9 | 10 | Pierre Gasly | Pierre Gasly | Pierre Gasly | Pierre Gasly | Pierre Gasly | Pierre Gasly | 10 | 5 |
| 10 | 31 | Esteban Ocon | Esteban Ocon | Esteban Ocon | Esteban Ocon | Esteban Ocon | Esteban Ocon | 10 | 5 |
| 11 | 14 | Fernando Alonso | Fernando Alonso | Fernando Alonso | Fernando Alonso | Fernando Alonso | Fernando Alonso | 16 | 6 |
| 12 | 18 | Lance Stroll | Lance Stroll | Lance Stroll | Lance Stroll | Lance Stroll | Lance Stroll | 18 | 6 |
| 13 | 16 | Charles Leclerc | Charles Leclerc | Charles Leclerc | Charles Leclerc | Charles Leclerc | Charles Leclerc | 17 | 7 |
| 14 | 16 | Carlos Sainz | Carlos Saihz | Carlos Sainz | Carlos Sainz | Carlos Sairiz | Carlos Sainz | 55 | 7 |
| 15 | 20 | Kevin Magnussen | Kevin Magnussen | Kevin Magnussen | Kevin Magnussen | Kevin Magnussen | Kevin Magnussen | 21 | 8 |
| 16 | 27 | Nico Hulkenberg | Nico Hulkenberg | Nico Hulkenberg | Nico Hulkenberg | Nico Hulkenberg | Nico Hulkenberg | 3 | 8 |
| 17 | 4 | Lando Norris | Lando Norris | Lando Norris | Lando Norris | Lando Norris | Lando Norris | 2 | 9 |
| 18 | 81 | Oscar Piastri | Oscar Piastri | Oscar Piastri | Oscar Piastri | Oscar Piastri | Oscar Piastri | 19 | 9 |
| 19 | 2 | Logan Sargeant | Logan Sargeant | Logan Sargeant | Logan Sargeant | Logan Sargeant | Logan Sargeant | 9 | 10 |
| 20 | 23 | Alexander Albon | Alexander Albon | Alexander Albon | Alexander Albon | AlexanderAlbon | AlexanderAlbon | 20 | 10 |

There is a second table for the results that is exactly the same as the race table.

[Table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4pDX.jpg)

| id | race_id | pole_position | 1e | 2e | 3e | snelste_ronde |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Now what I'm trying to achieve is, when the keys in race and result match on raceID, UserID and driver correct prediction, a number of points are posted in a table. I now manage to make and check queries with sql, but then I cannot enter that value so that the position can be made up. Anyone have an idea to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

---

This is what I hope to accomplish:

[image: Result I hope to get and store in SQL database]

Some code I use to check if prediction is correct is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `race`;
SELECT * FROM uitslag;

SELECT Pole_position, 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM uitslag
            WHERE uitslag.pole_position=race.Pole_position
            AND uitslag.race_id=race.id_race
        )
        THEN '5'
        ELSE '0'
    END
FROM race;

SELECT 1e,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM uitslag
            WHERE uitslag.1e = race.1e
            AND uitslag.race_id = race.id_race
        )
        THEN '15'
        ELSE '0'
    END
FROM race;
```

Outcome of this query will be like:

[image: Query example pole position]

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but I think this is what you were looking for:

```sql
SELECT
    `r`.`id_voorspel`, `r`.`id_user`, `r`.`id_race`,
    IF (`r`.`Pole_position` = `p`.`pole_position`, 5, 0) AS `pole_position`,
    IF(`r`.`1e` = `p`.`1e`, 25, 0) AS `1e`,
    IF(`r`.`2e` = `p`.`2e`, 18, 0) AS `2e`,
    IF(`r`.`3e` = `p`.`3e`, 15, 0) AS `3e`,
    IF(`r`.`sr` = `p`.`snelste_ronde`, 10, 0) AS `snelste_ronde`,
    (
        IF (`r`.`Pole_position` = `p`.`pole_position`, 5, 0) +
        IF(`r`.`1e` = `p`.`1e`, 25, 0) +
        IF(`r`.`2e` = `p`.`2e`, 18, 0) +
        IF(`r`.`3e` = `p`.`3e`, 15, 0) +
        IF(`r`.`sr` = `p`.`snelste_ronde`, 10, 0)
    ) AS `total`
FROM `race` `r`
JOIN `uitslag` `p` ON `r`.`id_race` = `p`.`race_id`;
```